# AmCharts4: How to hide percentage in legend label in Pie chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, pie-chart, amcharts4

I do not want to show the percentage in legends in Pie Chart. How can I disable that? Following is the code-

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 *
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 *
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "Lithuania",
  "litres": 501.9
}, {
  "country": "Czechia",
  "litres": 301.9
}, {
  "country": "Ireland",
  "litres": 201.1
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "litres": 165.8
}, {
  "country": "Australia",
  "litres": 139.9
}, {
  "country": "Austria",
  "litres": 128.3
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "litres": 99
}, {
  "country": "Belgium",
  "litres": 60
}, {
  "country": "The Netherlands",
  "litres": 50
}];

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.labels.template.text = "[bold {color}]{name} : {value} [/]";

// Add and configure Series
var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "litres";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "country";
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

In the code below, I just want to show legends as `Name : Value` but it is appending percentage values next to it. How can I remove that? Attaching the screenshot below for the same,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
   chart.legend.valueLabels.template.disabled = true;
```